# How get Week day name in custom format using vb.net/C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, string, datetime, weekday

Using following code get the current Day Name of a computer

```
Dim CompCurrCult = Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
Dim dayOfWeek As DayOfWeek = CompCurrCult .Calendar.GetDayOfWeek(Date.Today)
```

Result : `dayofWeek = Monday`

So my question is how to get the result like `MON` instead of `Monday`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`Calendar.GetDayOfWeek` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getdayofweek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns full day name of a `DateTime` which provided as a parameter and it's based on [`DayOfWeek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enumeration.

You can use [`"ddd"` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dddSpecifier) to get abbreviated name of the day. For C#;

```
DateTime.Today.ToString("ddd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //Mon
```

If you want to get it as `MON`, just call [`.ToUpper()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.toupper(v=vs.110).aspx) like;

```
DateTime.Today.ToString("ddd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToUpper(); // MON
```

Comment: Call ToUpper() to get the "MON"

Answer (score 2):

Use *substring* function

```
Dim DayName As String = UCase(dayOfWeek.ToString.Substring(0, 3))
```

Comment: _Well_, I honestly don't like to use substring in this case because an abbreviated name of a day is not always the first 3 characters. For example; my current culture is `tr-TR` and `Monday` is called `Pazartesi` in Turkish. But it's abbreviated name is `Pzt` not `Paz`. Yes, your code will work in this case but it is not suitable for all cases.

Comment: @SonerGönül Fine that you showed some interest on my Answer, I've answered According to the given Example Only